# Помогите более эффективно решить задачу по С++

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Задача:

> Заданная матрица целых положительных чисел N x M (N <= 100, M <= 100), нужно посчитать количество подматриц, сумма элементов которых больше или равно  A(0< A <= 1000000) и меньше или равно B (A <= B <= 1000000)

Пример:

```
Пусть N = 2 , M = 3 , A = 4 , B = 5 
И пусть задана такая матрица :
1  2  3 
4  5  2 

Существует 5 подматрицы суммы элементов которых удовлетворяют условие :

1)1
  4

2)2 3

3)3 
  2

4)4 

5)5
```

Мой код :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
const int N = 2 , M = 3 ; 

long long  Matrix[N][M];
long long Aux[N][M];

void Read_matrix(){
        for(int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++)
            for(int j  = 0 ; j < M ; j++)
                cin >> Matrix[i][j];
}

void Build_Aux (){
    for(int i= 0 ; i < M; i++)
        Aux[0][i] = Matrix[0][i];

     for(int i = 1 ; i < N ; i++)
        for(int j = 0 ; j < M ; j++)
            Aux[i][j] =Matrix[i][j] + Aux[i-1][j];

    for(int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++)
        for(int j = 1 ; j < M ; j++)
            Aux[i][j]  +=  Aux[i][j-1];
}




long long  SumQuery(int tli, int tlj, int rbi, int rbj)
{

    long long res = Aux[rbi][rbj];


    if (tli > 0)
       res = res - Aux[tli-1][rbj];


    if (tlj > 0)
       res = res - Aux[rbi][tlj-1];


    if (tli > 0 && tlj > 0)
       res = res + Aux[tli-1][tlj-1];

    return res;
}

int Answer(long long  a , long long  b){
    int ans = 0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < N; i++)
            for(int j = 0 ;  j < M ; j++)
                for(int y = i ; y < N ; y++)
                    for(int x = j ; x < M ; x++)
                        if(a<=SumQuery(i,j,y,x) && SumQuery(i,j,y,x)<=b)
                            ans++;
    return ans ;
}

int main()
{
    Read_matrix();
    Build_Aux();
    long long a = 4 , b = 5;
    cout << Answer(a , b);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приведённый алгоритм четвёртой степени (O(n^4)). Можно сделать кубический (O(n^3)) с использованием [префиксных сумм](http://brestprog.by/topics/prefixsums/)  - они уже, как я понимаю, лежат в `Aux`

Для каждой пары строк `y1,y2`, применив метод двух указателей (индексов столбцов), можно подсчитать количество подматриц, заключённых между указанными строками, с суммой, не превышающей `B`. А также количество подматриц c суммой, меньшей `A`. Разность этих количеств - число подматриц с суммой в нужном диапазоне.

[Пример для одномерного массива](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/number-of-subarrays-having-sum-in-a-given-range/)